# Core Data One-to-Many Relationship

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, core-data

I have a one-to-many relationship in my Core Data model.  One meal can have multiple foods.  I want to populate a table with the the foods from one meal.  So if Meal #1 has Apples, Oranges, and Lemons, then the table would consist of those three foods.

Any help is very appreciated because I am completely stuck.

Here is my model:

[image]

And the NSManagedObject Classes:

Meal.h

```
@class Food;

@interface Meal : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *foods;

@end

@interface Meal (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addFoodsObject:(Food *)value;
- (void)removeFoodsObject:(Food *)value;
- (void)addFoods:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeFoods:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

Food.h

```
@class Meal;

@interface Food : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Meal *meals;

@end
```

Here is the code where I cam trying to attempt this, but I am having some issues.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController 
{    
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
        return _fetchedResultsController;

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Food" inManagedObjectContext:_context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Meal.foods == %@", entity]];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];

    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    [fetchRequest release];
    [theFetchedResultsController release];

    return _fetchedResultsController;      
}
```

Comment: What are you stuck on? Please tell us exactly what your problems are.

Comment: Why use a one-to-many relationship here? If `Food` represents a *kind* of food rather than a particular piece of food, then I'd expect a given `Food` instance to be able to be related to more than one meal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention that you are having issues, but not what the issues are; but your `NSFetchRequest` predicate doesn't look right to me.  Also `meals` defined on `Food` is plural but the relationship is To-one -- a little confusing.

Your UITableView should be populated with the `Food`s from a single `Meal`, right?  Let's call that `Meal` `_thisMeal`, then the fetch predicate should be:

```
NSPredicate *foodPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"meals == %@",_thisMeal];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:foodPredicate];
```

So, the entity you're fetching is `Food`; and this predicate ensures that their `meals` property is the `Meal` your UITableViewController is looking for.

Updated to show how to fetch a named `Meal`

To fetch a `Meal` named "Custom Meal":

```
Meal *_thisMeal = nil;
// this assumes that there should be only one Meal named "Custom Meal"
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Meal"];
NSPredicate *fetchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@",@"Custom Meal"];

NSError *fetchError = nil;
NSArray *meals = [_context executeFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError];
if( fetchError )
    NSLog(@"%s - ERROR while fetching Meal: %@,%@",__FUNCTION__,fetchError,[fetchError userInfo]);
else if( [meals count] != 0 )
    _thisMeal = [meals objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Can you explain the Meal _thisMeal? This line will give me errors Meal *_thisMeal.  What should that line be?

Comment: Sorry, my point was that your `UITableViewController` must 'know' what Meal is being displayed in order for your `NSFetchRequest` to work.  Presumably, it gets a Meal reference from somewhere upstream, perhaps after being selected in a previous table view.  For the sake of discussion, I just called it `_thisMeal` because I don't know, in your code, what the reference to the specific Meal is.

Comment: Can you show me how to get the Meal _thisMeal?  Let's say I want a meal Meal named "Custom Meal", then I wan to display the foods that are in Custom Foods.  This whole concept is confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

Your Meal and Food classes are wrong. It's best to kill those and let XCode auto re-generate 
those classes via (make sure your entity is selected):

[image]

In your `fetchedResultsController` getter method, kill the line:

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Meal.foods == %@", entity]];
```

You would normally use a predicate to filter your data, such as foods that contain a banana. Your current predicate doesn't really make sense at the moment. It's saying "give me meals that contain a food called 'entity',...doesn't make sense.

Since you want to get meals...

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Food" inManagedObjectContext:_context];
```

should be:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Meal" inManagedObjectContext:_context];
```

(note the `@"Meal"`).

You would then access the foods from each meal via `meal.foods`.

This line:
`self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;`
should be:
`_fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;`
What you did is basically call the method you are currently in.